# Lose saved data on app update

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

When creating a new version of my Unity3D app, I tested sideloading the new version on top of a from-the-store install.  The sideloaded app was no longer able to find the files saved from the from-the-store version.

It seems as though the issue is that Application.persistentDataPath differs between the two app versions.

Under BuildSettings:

```
Install Location: Prefer External
Write Access:     Internal Only
```

The AndroidManifest.xml seems to have no information about the install location/write access location.

I wouldn't mind changing the Install Location to Force Internal, if that helps with this update and/or in the future.  But I am unsure what that setting does.

I'm saving XML files using C#'s XMLSerializer and then writing them to a FileStream using Application.persistentDataPath.

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof([CLASS]));
FileStream stream = new FileStream( Application.persistentDataPath + "/[FILENAME].xml", FileMode.Create);    
serializer.Serialize( stream, [OBJECT]);    
stream.Close();
```

Comment: What code are you using to save your data? PlayerPrefs usually works fine for me.

Comment: Modified question to include more details.  Thanks for asking, I forgot that I had to not use PlayerPrefs early on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try saving the XML string in the PlayerPrefs like so:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("SaveGameName", yourXML);
```

and get it like so:

```
myxml = PlayerPrefs.GetString("SaveGameName");
```

In the past the PlayerPrefs class worked well for me for persistent data. I know for a fact this data persists even if you install new versions from the app store.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html here is the docs on it.

Comment: Oh I see you can't use playerprefs like you said in a comment. Not sure how you will circumvent this problem in that case.

Comment: In theory Application.persistentDataPath will let me save files in a similar location.  However, it seems to change on updates.

Comment: I agree with you that this is confusing. I see in the docs that the bundle identifier forms part of the path. Could it be that this ID has changed? I can't remember if the app store even allows you to upload a build with a different bundle ID. From the docs: "If you keep the same Bundle Identifier in future versions then the app will continue accessing the same location on every update."

Comment: The bundle identifier is consistent.